# Are there distros with ptrace_scope set to zero by default?

Tags: ubuntu, trace

I wanted to use `ptrace` on a recent version of Ubuntu to inspect the memory of any other process running under the same OS user. However, I quickly stumbled upon

> Operation not permitted

After a quick web search I found that:

> In Ubuntu 10.10 and later, users cannot ptrace processes that are not a descendant of the debugger. The behavior is controllable through the /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope sysctl, available via Yama.

I know that I can set this value to 0 and then do what I want. However, I was wondering if there exist any Linux distros which have `ptrace_scope` set to zero by default?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are. For example Debian briefly made `ptrace_scope=1` the default then [switched back](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=712740).

The protection afforded by disabling `ptrace` to non-child processes is somewhat limited: it prevents a real but narrow range of exploits, and at a small but non-negigible cost. An attacker who is in a position to run `ptrace` from a process running as some user can already run arbitrary processes as that user and access all of that user's files. Thus the `ptrace_scope` restrictions only protects privileges and confidential information of already-running processes, a typical case being a running key agent process (`ssh-agent`, `gpg-agent`, `gnome-keyring-daemon`, …) which has secrets entered by the user in its memory. The cost of the restriction is that applications can't use `ptrace` except to control a process that they started; this allows use cases like running a process under `gdb` or `fakeroot` but not use cases like attaching a debugger to a running program or `reptyr`.

Comment: Good to know that Debian yanked it back out.  A process can call prctl and make itself not traceable with ptrace anyway, if it thinks it is going to hold data someone might be after.

Answer (score -1):

If there are, there shouldn't be.  Most of them switched shortly after:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAj2_-KWeoo

Short: A smart fellow decided to implement create-remote-thread on linux via ptrace to inject code in to foreign processes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer hbdgaf. Jugaad is precisely what I tried :) However, I didn't find any source on the Internet which states that most distros switched `ptrace_scope` to 1 by default. Although, I agree that they should.

Comment: In point of fact redhat did it before debian and canonical.  Some Debian or Ubuntu enthusiast blogged raging about it and calling the decision retarded.  I had to make this explanation to them, and explain that they shouldn't call a decision retarded without understanding the Why.  If I wanted to use something like Jugaad in an offensive environment, it would be with some LD-PRELOAD tweak to inject a tiny .so in to every process and wait for one of them to escalate to root.  Then flip the switch for me.  So all I had to do is wait.